# I need help linking cross platform flutter app to firebase on windows

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am developing an android/ios app using android studio on windows. My question is do I have to link both the ios and the android parts of the app to my firebase server? If yes, how do I link the ios app as well keeping in mind that I’m developing on windows?

Comment: This is unclear. "how do I link the ios app as well keeping in mind that I’m developing on windows". Firebase is a database, connect to it using the code you need for the platform you are using. So yes, whichever platform you are using, you will need to connect to it. You could use something like Xamarin with 1 code base, but it doesn't sound you're going that route

Comment: @ViaTech I meant if I only link the android app will the ios version also work with firebase? And where do I add the config file of the ios version to the project on android studio?

Comment: back when I used Android Studio it did not have IOS support (I only used Java for Android). So with that I cannot help as I do not currently know the internals of how that works. But this seems like a solid tutorial https://kotlinlang.org/docsmultiplatform-mobile-integrate-in-existing-app.html

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below, instead of as an edit on your question. That way more people are likely to find it, and the system also knows that you've been helped. Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow#:~:text=Click%20the%20green%20outlined%20checkmark,%22has%20an%20accepted%20answer%22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. You have to have xcode installed, so I installed mac os on a vm and linked both the android app using vscode and the ios using xcode. Here are two helpful videos:
https://youtu.be/Lq8J-vFqH7w
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnpGU8vj7TI